# Given a number, quickly check which interval it is in?

Tags: matlab

Assume I have four intervals: [0, 82), [82, 146), [146, 180), [180, 255].

Given a number, let's say 110. I want to quickly check which interval is 110 in, return 1 or 2 or 3 or 4.

I am wondering if MATLAB has existing functions to do rather than comparing the number manually.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like this -

```
intv = [
    0    82;
    82  146;
    146 180;
    180 255]

num = 110

index = find(num>=intv(:,1) & num<intv(:,2))
```

---

If the interval array were a row vector: `intv = [0 82 146 180 255]`, you can use -

```
index = find(num >= intv(1:end-1) & num < intv(2:end))
```

Or use `histc` -

```
index = find(histc(num,intv))
```

As suggested by @knedlsepp, for more than one input numbers as `num`, you can use -

```
[~,indices] = histc(num, intv)
```

Comment: For more than one point `[~,indices] = histc(num, intv)` would also work great.

Comment: Great comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 4):

If each interval ends where the next interval begins (as in your example), and if the number is always assured to lie in one of those intervals, you can determine the interval *for several numbers at once*:

```
int_bounds = [82 146 180]; %// omit first (0) and last (255) endpoints
numbers = [100 50 146 250];; %// which interval are those numbers in?
result = sum(bsxfun(@ge, numbers(:).', int_bounds(:)), 1)+1;
```

In this example the result is

```
result =
     2     1     3     4
```

Comment: Love this! Beautiful use of bsxfun!

Comment: If you don't mind, There is a typo.. either `result` should be `2 3 4` or you are missing a number next to `100`.

Comment: @SanthanSalai Thanks! Yes, I included `50` in my tests but forgot to update the answer. Fixed now!